# How can I implement Enhanced Messaging in an LWC component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lms, messaging

I've read this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_enhanced_messaging_lwc_events.htm), but the example right there is for an aura component. Where can I find more info about it? Does anyone know how to implement these events? Where can I put those tags?